# how to remove searched item and remove that item from array?

Tags: javascript

I have a search field and in that field I can search an item. Then I have to remove it, but unfortunately I don`t know how I can remove that item. Please, could you help me with that. I tried the following: 
If`id`of`currentRobot`is equal to`current id` then delete that item, but I guess it is not quite right, cause it is not working
[image]
My code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentRobot=null;

    for( var i=0; i<robots.length; i++){

        var robot = document.createElement('div');

        robotsContainer.appendChild(robot);

        robot.className='whole-block';  
        robot.setAttribute('id', robots[i].id);


        robot.innerHTML += "<img src='" + robots[i].avatar + "'>";
        robot.innerHTML += "<h3>" +robots[i].first_name + "</h3>";
        robot.innerHTML += "<h3>" +robots[i].last_name + "</h3>";
        robot.innerHTML += "<p>" +robots[i].email + "</p>";
        robot.innerHTML += "<p>" +robots[i].gender + "</p>";
        robot.innerHTML += "<p>" +robots[i].friends + "</p>";

    }   
        console.log(value)
    value.onkeyup = function(e){
        currentRobot=e.target.value;
        var robots = document.querySelectorAll("div[id]:not([id='"+ this.value +"']):not([id='robotsContainer'])");
        for(var i = 0; i < robots.length; i++ ){
            if(this.value==""){ 
                robots[i].style.display="block";
            } else {
                robots[i].style.display="none";
            }
        };

    };


 var button= document.getElementById('button');  
        button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
             e.preventDefault(); 

        for(var i = 0; i < robots.length; i++){
                if (robots[i].id ===  currentRobot) robots.splice(i, 1);

        }
        }, false);

});
```

Comment: do you want to delete it or hide it?

Comment: i want delete it from array

Comment: Check the condition `robots[i].id ===  currentRobot`, ensure those two values are what you expect. You didn't provide the data you are using, we can't help that much or give a definitive answer without a runnable example. Finally I'd like to note removing it won't hide it right away, you need to re-trigger `keyup` or hide it in the `click` event for it to be hidden as it's not removed from the DOM.

Comment: Where is your global robots variable initialised?

Comment: Where is `robots` defined? Is it also in the outer scope available? If not, that might be the problem. You define it in the inner scope of a function that is not available globally. Also be aware that `  if(this.value==""){ ` may return `true` if `this.value` is a falsey value. To deep equal check both values use `===`

Answer (score 0):

You are assiging `currentRobot`

```
currentRobot=e.target.value;
```

and then you are comparing its value

```
  if (robots[i].id ===  currentRobot) robots.splice(i, 1);
```

My hunch is that `currentRobot` and `robots[i.id` is not of the same type.  Before the comparison try adding

```
console.log( currentRobot, robots[i].id);
```

They need to be of the same data type for this comparison to work.

Also, please keep in mind that the first index of an array is `0` not `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the global `robots` is, we must guess.

#### 1. `robots` is a true array

If `robots` is a true JavaScript array, then the removal from the array should work with `splice`, but:

- you should better exit the loop as soon as you do that
- this removal will have no effect on your page

So, your code could deal with that as follows:

So replace this:

```
if (robots[i].id === currentRobot) robots.splice(i, 1);
```

..with:

```
if (robots[i].id === currentRobot) {
    var node = document.getElementById(currentRobot);
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    robots.splice(i, 1);
    break; // and exit loop!
}
```

#### 2. `robots` is an HTML Collection

If your global variable `robots` is an HTML collection, then it is array-like, but not a true array, so you cannot apply `splice` on them. Instead you must use DOM methods.

So then replace this:

```
if (robots[i].id === currentRobot) robots.splice(i, 1);
```

..with:

```
if (robots[i].id === currentRobot) {
    robots[i].parentNode.removeChild(roots[i]);
    break; // and exit loop!
}
```

You need to exit the loop, as it will be awkward to continue the loop on a mutating HTML Collection, and it also is not necessary, since you expect only one match any way.

Comment: so Html Elements have an avatar and friends? :/

Comment: I don't know really what `robots` is. It is confusing  as OP uses the same name for local variables. I asked the question in a comment, but OP does not reply. BTW, you can define properties on HTML element objects.